# Hide <select> tag in HTML using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

Good day!

I need help again on solving this problem.

I want to hide the Drop down list when a user click the 'Other' value and replace by a hidden text box which will appear after the user choose 'Other', but it's not working on my case. Here's my code:

```js
function addMajorList(){
    if(document.getElementById('courseMajor').value == 'other'){
        document.getElementById('addMajorToList').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <select class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" name="courseMajor" id="courseMajor">
    <?php
        for ($i=0;$i<count($getMajorList);$i++){   
    ?>
          <option value=<?php echo $getMajorList[$i][0]?>><?php echo $getMajorList[$i][1];?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
          <option value="other" onchange="addMajorList()">Other</option>
    </select>
    <input class="form-control info" type="hidden" id="addMajorToList" name="addMajorToList">
</div>
```

Comment: try putting your onchange event inside the <select> tag not the <option> tag

Comment: As @Redan said, think about it this way... the value of the `select` changes, the value of the specific `option` tag does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I have changed onchange event to select tag instead hidden field I have created text input and add CSS to hide and show, and I have removed your php part of code for OP.

```js
 function addMajorList(){
        if(document.getElementById('courseMajor').value == 'other'){
            document.getElementById('addMajorToList').style.display = "inline";
        }else{
            document.getElementById('addMajorToList').style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

```css
#addMajorToList{
display:none;
}
```

```html
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" name="courseMajor" id="courseMajor"  onchange="addMajorList()">
             <option value="oneother">One</option>
              <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
        <input class="form-control info" type="text" id="addMajorToList" name="addMajorToList">
    </div>
```

Comment: @Redan and Jon P mention correct your onchange event should be in select tag

Comment: @Kalaiselvan_A Thanks! your code is working but it's possible to hide the <select> tag after the user chose "Other"? and it will line on where the <select> tag located? as on your code it appears below the <select> tag

Comment: @Mark you mean wants to hide select and display a input in same place? While user choose other option

Comment: @Kalaiselvan_A yup if it's possible... but if the code is complex.. I will use your code.. thanks by the way :-)